# Why do RDS files differ (if they should be identical)?

Tags: r, dataframe, checksum, difference

I re-ran some old R code of mine. As a check, I calculated the md5sum of the resulting RDS file.
It was different from an older RDS file, which I thought was identical, because it was created with the same code.

I loaded both files into dataframes and it *seemed* like the content was the same.

I exported both dataframes as two csv files, they had the same checksum.

I exported both dataframes again as two RDS files, this resulted in two different checksums again (the same as for the RDS files in the beginning. )

I exported the head() of both dataframes as RDS, but including all rows (so actually the entire dataframes, same dataframes as the original loaded RDS files). (i.e. dataframe has 2255 rows, so I did `saveRDS(head(df1, n=2255), "head_df1.RDS")`

The checksum was now the same for both "head" files, but different from the two original RDS files.

How is that possible? What difference can there be between two RDS files with identical data?
How can the head() of a dataframe be different from the original RDS file?

Comment: Might be that it was saved using a different compression scheme. Also `saveRDS` changed in version 3.5.0. You can use the `version` argument to use the old version.

Comment: Are the data objects the same? try `identical(df1, df2)`. If that returns `FALSE` then thats your issue, otherwise I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: It's possible different compression settings we used between the files. it doesn't seem like a good idea to use the checksum of the RDS like a checksum on the data itself. If you want to checkum the data itself, consider instead a package like `digest`. Then you don't have to worry about any differences in how the data is serialized into the RDS format. It's totally possible for the exact same data to be encoded in different ways.

Comment: Ok I tried to go back in the versioning and forcing an older version on the `saveRDS` command. This did still result in two different files. The `identical(df1, df2)` command resulted in `TRUE`. This is a relief for me, thank you for this suggestion. However I would still be curious why this is happening. Thanks also for suggesting the `digest` package, I will have a look at this too if I have to compare data versions. This is definitely something I will have to face again, however in future I will not try to get checksums of the RDS files anymore.